# <lightning-formatted-rich-text> converting string to email formatting

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, string, regular-expressions

I am currently writing a basic search users UI which can search email of users and return  based on a search string and bolds the matching chars in the result. I achieve this by adding  tags in JS and displaying using , the issue I am having is when I put an email into  it always converts to a blue clickable hyperlink, basically converts any '.com' string into this format.

Is there anyway around this? Either a way to display HTML tags in LWC without this tag or a way to remove this formatting from the rich text tag.

Ex searching 'a': https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6oZK.png

Right now I am trying to implement something like, splitting the string into smaller strings that dont have periods '.' and then looping through those strings for display in the rich text, but man that feels wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `disable-linkify` to the component.